# Knockout. How to execute custom code before and after observable updates

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have an array of users that are shown in a page. And i have a pair of input text boxes to filter the users shown by name and lastname.
I want that when any of the values at the input text fields changes, the array of users update.

Here is the code that i have to achive that:

Knockout viewmodel:

```
function HomeViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.users = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.FilterByName = ko.observable('');
    self.FilterByLastName = ko.observable('');

    self.FilteredUsers = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.FilteredUsersComputed = ko.computed(function () {
        var result = self.users().filter(function (user) {
            return (user.name.toUpperCase().includes(self.FilterByName().toUpperCase()) &&
                user.lastName.toUpperCase().includes(self.FilterByLastName().toUpperCase())
            );
        });
        self.FilteredUsers(result);
    });

    $.getJSON("/api/User", function (data) {            
        self.users(data);
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new HomeViewModel());
```

HTML:

```
        <div>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input data-bind="textInput: FilterByName" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Lastname:</label>
            <input data-bind="textInput: FilterByLastName" />
        </div>

(...)

        <div id="LLAdminBodyMain" class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center" data-bind="foreach: FilteredUsers">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                    <p data-bind="text: name"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

QUESTION:

Now i want to get the following effect:

1. Delay the execution of the `FilteredUsers`' computed function to not fire each time a key is pressed in the Name or Lastname fields. i.e: wait until there are no keypress events for 2 seconds; or just wait for 1 or 2 seconds after kepress to execute the computed function.
2. When `FilteredUsers` is fired, first fade out `LLAdminBodyMain`, then update the `FilteredUsers` and then fade in `LLAdminBodyMain` with the new elements.

To do that i think that would be useful to know how to detect when knockout is going to update an observable and execute my custom code just before it updates and propagates the new value.

I've tried to do something similar, but the following code does not work: knockout doesn't detect changes anymore.

```
 self.FilteredUsersComputed = ko.computed(function () {
        console.log("In");
        $("#LLAdminBodyMain").fadeOut(function () {
            var result = self.users().filter(function (user) {
                return (user.name.toUpperCase().includes(self.FilterByName().toUpperCase()) &&
                    user.lastName.toUpperCase().includes(self.FilterByLastName().toUpperCase())
                );
            });
            self.FilteredUsers(result);
        }).delay(1000).fadeIn();

    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html

Answer (score 0):

> Delay the execution of the FilteredUsers' computed function to not fire each time a key is pressed in the Name or Lastname fields. i.e: wait until there are no keypress events for 2 seconds; or just wait for 1 or 2 seconds after kepress to execute the computed function.

See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html. Also it's better to have a computer observable just return the computed value instead of setting a separate observable.

```
self.FilteredUsers = ko.computed(function () {
    var result = self.users().filter(function (user) {
        return (user.name.toUpperCase().includes(self.FilterByName().toUpperCase()) &&
            user.lastName.toUpperCase().includes(self.FilterByLastName().toUpperCase())
        );
    });
    return result;
}).extend({ rateLimit: {timeout: 2000, method: "notifyWhenChangesStop"} });
```

> When FilteredUsers is fired, first fade out LLAdminBodyMain, then update the FilteredUsers and then fade in LLAdminBodyMain with the new elements.

You'll want to use the `afterAdd` and `beforeRemove` callbacks of `foreach`.
See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-7-post-processing-or-animating-the-generated-dom-elements and http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html